# DeMorgan's commentary on Euclid's Elements

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Augustus DeMorgan wrote comments on Euclid's *Elements*, which capture many of the most important points.  Heath quotes them extensively.

I cannot find any source for the original: Where can I see DeMorgan's comments in the original?

Comment: Related: Henry Law, [The_Elements of Euclid with Many Additional Propositions (1860)](https://books.google.it/books?id=ImTmkBZhRBIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false) as well as Isaac Todhunter, [The Elements of Euclid for the Use of Schools and Colleges/Notes (1872)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Euclid_for_the_Use_of_Schools_and_Colleges/Notes)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

De Morgan's "Short Supplementary Remarks on the first Six Books of Euclid's Elements" is contained in the [Companion to the (British) Almanac for the year 1849](https://archive.org/details/sim_british-almanac-companion_1849/page/n3/mode/2up), pp.5–20, published by the [Society for the Diffusion of Useful Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Almanac).